# can TCP server script in C communicate with TCP client script in HTML5

Tags: c, html, tcp

i have a server connected with some client with LAN. And a script is running on the server in C language and i want to send some values to the clients on browser. How can i do that?﻿

Comment: You want to do a single HTTP request like GET or PUT, or you want to do WebSockets to have long-running communication?

Comment: i want to do it with WebSockets in html5 for the clients and for the server i can only use C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use libwebsockets: http://libwebsockets.org/trac/libwebsockets - it's designed for exactly this.